# Плавное исчезновение  страницы при клике на ссылку.

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
Задача:
При клике по ссылки, страница сначала плавно исчезает, а потом происходит переход.
Исходные данные:
//Код jquery
//Собираем все ссылки (анкоры) на страцице
$('a').click(function(){ 
             //Плавное погасание всей страницы
             $('#all').animate({opacity: 0},2000);
             //Переход на следюующую страницу. (проблема в этом месте, т.е. код выполняется параллельно и при нажатии на ссылку сразу возвращатеся return , вопрос: как сделать переход после того как страница погаснет?
``                 return true;
                                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/avengerweb/J7YD2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Используйте callback complete который можно передать в опциях функции animate, также чтобы предотвратить выполнение действия по умолчанию в данном случае на ссылках используйте preventDefault.
Пример **([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kison/FEryd/1/))**:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        var context = $(this);        
        $('body').animate({opacity: 0}, {
            speed : 2000,
            complete : function(){                
                var domain = location.hostname,
                    href =  context.prop('href');

                if (href.indexOf("http://") > -1) {
                    document.location.href = href;
                } else {
                    document.location.href = domain + href;                    
                }                                
            }
        });        
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: страница гаснет , но перехода не происходит. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: возможно из-за того, что переход внутри сайта

Comment: приведите пример ссылки

Comment: <a href="/контакты.html">Контакты</a>

Comment: Посмотрите обновления